# Windows 7 can't recognize CompactFlash cards on USB3.0

Tags: windows-7, usb-3, compact-flash

I have four CompactFlash readers (USB 3.0) connected by a 4-way hub to a USB 3.0 card in a PC running Windows 7 64-bit.

When I insert all four CF cards, sometimes some of them are not recognized (I don't see them in Explorer or in Device Manager).

The USB hub has four status lights per port. Sometimes the light of a port goes off (yet the CF reader is still attached) and then the card is not recognized. When I reconnect the reader, it works fine...